# Inequality with restriction

Tags: inequality

I have been trying to prove without success the following inequality. If $a,b,c,d>0$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=1$ then prove that $a+b+c+d+\frac{1}{abcd}\geq 18$.

Comment: You should describe the approaches you did try, even if unsuccessful.

Comment: This is just a guess and I have not worked it out yet...
Put $a = \cos\phi\cos\theta$, $b = \sin\phi\cos\theta$, $c = \cos\phi\sin\theta$ and $d = \sin\phi\sin\theta$ with $\theta,\phi\in[0,\pi/2]$.
Does that help?

Comment: @L__: be careful, you only parametrized the intersection of the hypersphere with $ad=bc$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, when $a=b=c=d=\dfrac{1}{2}$, the equality holds.

Now try to use
$$
\sum a+32\times\frac{1}{32abcd}\ge 36 \sqrt[36]{\frac{abcd}{(32abcd)^{32}}}.
$$

Notice also that $1=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2\ge 4\sqrt{abcd}$, we complete the proof.

Comment: Ma Ming, please explain in details how did you get right hand side of the inequality. In particulat how did you get 36?

Comment: @user61810 $4+32=36$.

Comment: Write down all details please. You have skipped something which is not obvious at all.